# Windows Service will not write to log file in loop

Tags: c#, logging, windows-services, event-log

I am writing my first windows service and to start with it's just writing to a log file, which is working perfectly.  I actually need the service to loop through the entries in a json file, which I have used elsewhere with no issues.  So my service initiates a timer, and fires an event every 60 seconds;

```
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
timer.Interval = 60000; // 60 seconds  
timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.OnTimer);
timer.Start();
```

This works absolutely perfectly and my OnTimer event is thus;

```
public void OnTimer(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs args)
    {
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("Drive Space monitoring initiated", EventLogEntryType.Information, eventId++);
    }
```

This puts the entry in the log exactly as I expect every 60 seconds. My problem comes when I try to add a loop to the OnTimer event.  For simplicity, here is what I added;

```
int count = 4;
for(int x = 1; x <= count; x++)
{
    string msg = "This is just a counter: " + x.ToString();
    eventLog1.WriteEntry(msg, EventLogEntryType.Information, eventId++);
}
```

This has absolutely no effect and no further entries are added to my log file when the OnTimer event fires.

Comment: the code looks fine, but did you check the EventViewer if there any exceptions ?

Comment: Can you use System.Threading.Timer instead of System.Timers.Timer

Comment: @HanyHabib - no exceptions in the event viewer

Comment: @PSK - I will try, but I'm not a programmer, just trying to get by!

Comment: I vaguely remember that eventlog does not allow adding events too fast in succession. Also the EventViewer is late is displaying new events.
Please try adding a Thread.Sleep(10) as a test in the for loop, and maybe set the counter to 2, as a test.

Comment: @PepitoSh - made no difference I am afraid

Comment: @PSK - this worked!  if you can make your suggestion a solution I can up vote it.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `System.Threading.Timer` instead of `System.Timers.Timer`.

`System.Timers.Timer` gives issue some time when used in windows service and it will swallow all the exceptions.